# Display a Excel chart in Html page

Tags: javascript, html, excel, charts

I have a EXCEL file containing multiple Tables and Charts.
I want to create a web page to display a particular Table and a Chart. I used java script to display the table.
But cant find a way to display the CHART. By chart i mean it contains a pie graph or bar graph.

Is it possible to display using java script? Or do i have to use JSP/something else?

Comment: I hope this link (http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15821/HTML-Vertical-Bar-Chart) help you for your required solution.

Comment: @GhostAnswer thanks, but this link shows how to make use of div to draw a graph. Its a good trick but i actually want to display the graph that is already drawn in my excel file.

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [Google Chart Tools](https://developers.google.com/chart/). Here is an [example](https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) with javascript source code. If you are building the table on the server side, you may instead want to pass the data down JSON encoded and then build both the table and chart at the same time without having to pass the data twice.

Comment: Google Chart Tools looks good , let me see whether it works for me. 
I was hoping some native HTML coding. Isn't anything available?

Comment: Google Chart Tools uses HTML5/SVG, so it is native (you aren't just getting an image response from Google). Google has also written these tools to save you a lot of headache doing it yourself (not to mention Google Chart Tools are interactive and look amazing!).

Comment: Google charts seemed excellent, until i realized it sends data to Google Servers.Close of chapter, which is a pity since it's such a great product!

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to use a free tool like oomfo, which is a PowerPoint plugin to create charts. It lets you pull data from excel, create charts and then export the entire slide as HTML - the charts are in Flash and JavaScript (fallback). Just add a line of code in the output web page to render JavaScript charts only.